# How can I check if a GameObject have any Components at all of any type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
selected.GetComponent()
```

selected is a GameObject and I want to find if it have any Components at all and not only specific one or by type.

Comment: I have a small question. When creating a new empty GameObject without adding any components it's still counting 1 component. Is the Transform in a GameObject is a component ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately it's this simple

```
Component[] allOfThem = GetComponents<Component>();
```

That's for "this" game object, or of course `selected.GetComponents<Component>()` for your game object `selected`.

So, when you think about it ..

```
Component[] stuff = GetComponents<Weapons>();
```

.. that will give you everything that is a **subclass** of Weapons.

```
Component[] ux = GetComponents<UnityEditor.UI.Button>();
```

.. that will give you everything that is a subclass of Button.

```
Component[] stuff = GetComponents<Enemies>();
```

.. that will give you everything that is a subclass of Enemies.

And so this ...

```
Component[] stuff = GetComponents<Component>();
```

will give you everything that is a Component!

You can't "attach" it to a game object unless it's a `Component` so that's what you want.

Comment: Except `UnityEditor.UI` is not a class that inherits from `Component` but a namespace ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following? As I know all components extends the base `Component` class.

```
Component[] components = selected.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
```

Comment: Welcome new user!  While totally correct, in Unity you'd probably want to use the new syntax.  Cheers!

Comment: @Fattie I have a small question. When creating a new empty GameObject without adding any components it's still counting 1 component. Is the Transform in a GameObject is a component ?

Comment: @PassetCronUs Then why when I'm doing: Component[] components = selected.GetComponents(typeof(Component)); andthe select object is empty have only transform it's still counting 1 component ?

Comment: Ah right empty GameObject count 1 component. The answer: https://answers.unity.com/questions/631007/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-empty.html Indeed the Transform is count as Component. So if I want to check if a GameObject is empty or have component I need to check the counting against 1 and not 0.

Comment: Component[] components = selected.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
    if (components.Length == 0) Should be: if (components.Length == 1)

Comment: @PassetCronUs You're wrong. [MonoBehaviour derives from Behaviour, which derives from Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) (and [Transform is also a Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)).

Comment: @Fattie this syntax is okey. It is often just easier to use the generic version because usually you don't search for type `Component` but a more specific one and would have to typecast everytime.

Comment: hi @derHugo.  I really don't understand your comment. The *question is about* searching for `Component`.  I've no idea what you mean on this occasion, sorry.

Comment: `While totally correct, in Unity you'd probably want to use the new syntax` .. I just said the current syntax may be `old` but it is ok. The `new` syntax you are talking about is not that `new` it is just a generic alternative which is faster to use because you don't have to typecast. But for actually finding `Component` as you say the current syntax is as valid and simple as the generic one

Answer (score 0):

//ищу компонент Comp1 на объекте если его нет то добавляем на объект
// подстраивайте под ваши нужды

```
public GameObject[] obj;

int[] numeric = new int[] {1,2,3,4 };
if (obj[0].GetComponent("Comp" + numeric[0]) == false) { obj[0].AddComponent(Type.GetType("Comp" + numeric[0])); }
```